# excel VBA Create checkbox function

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I am working on a function that creates a checkbox. So far I have written the following code. the  code below does not work instead it displays an error.  Any ideas??

```
 Sub test()
ActiveCell.Offset(, 1) = Sample(Shp)
End Sub


Function Sample(Shp as shape) 

    '~~> Create a Checkbox
    Set Shp = Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes.Add(52.5, 3, 42, 17.25)
End Function
```

Comment: What is Shp defined as in test? Also why are you rediming it in Sample? Sample is also not returning anything for you to set ActiveCell.Offset(, 1) equal to?

Comment: Declaring the variable twice is a mistake. Il edit that now. But the function below to create the checkbox that should work right?

Comment: Ive noticed sample function is empty not referencing the Shp. Why is this? However does not break and a checkbox is added to the spreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't compile at all.

The subroutine `Test` raises a mismatch error when calling the function `Sample`, because you're passing `Nothing` when the function is expecting to receive a `Shape` as a required argument/parameter.

Other things that I think are most likely wrong:

While you can certainly call a procedure to add a checkbox like you are doing:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(, 1) = Sample(Shp)
```

This is not actually going to assign the checkbox to the ActiveCell or anything.  The checkbox's location is hard-coded in the function that creates it.

Probably the function that creates the checkbox should be a subroutine (but that is ultimately dependent on your needs and preferences).  Unless you *need* to return a value (which you're not doing in this case), you should just use a subroutine.

So the solution would be to do something like:

```
Sub test()
    CreateTextBox Sheet1 '#Modify as needed
End Sub


Sub CreateTextBox(Optional sh As Worksheet)
    If sh Is Nothing Then Set sh = ActiveSheet
    sh.CheckBoxes.Add 52.5, 3, 42, 17.25
End Sub
```

If you want to put the checkbox in the `ActiveCell.Offset(,1)`, then do something like this instead:

```
Sub test()
    CreateTextBox ActiveCell.Offset(,1) '#Modify as needed
End Sub


Sub CreateTextBox(cl as Range)
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add cl.Left, cl.Top, 42, 17.25
End Sub
```

Comment: cl.Worksheet instead of ActiveSheet would make more sense. Although 100% unclear the OP could actually being trying to link `ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)` to the new CheckBox also? that would explain why he is setting it to a shape. maybe after insert he wants to set the `Shp.LinkedCell = ActiveCell.Offset(, 1)` of coarse this is 100% shot in pitch black darkness.